# Find objects with dates that are later than the current date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

In the `items` array, it looks for objects with dates that are later than the current date, `new Date ()`. `let findObject = this.state.items.find (date => new Date (date.date)> new Date ());` I display the found dates on the page. Problem: `let findObject = this.state.items.find (date => new Date (date.date)> new Date ());` finds only one object, and should find more.

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fm2g6y

```
class Item extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.findObject);

    return (   
        <li>
          <div>
            {moment(this.props.findObject.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
          </div>
        </li>
    )
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {

      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          date: 'Sun Oct 01 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          date: 'Fri Aug 23 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          date: 'Wed Oct 23 2019 04:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          date: 'Wed Oct 24 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          date: 'Thu Oct 05 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)'
        }]      
    };
  }


  render() {
    let findObject = this.state.items.find(date => new Date   (date.date) > new Date());

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.items
              .map((item, index) =>
                <Item
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  item={item}
                  findObject = {findObject}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In render return before map add filter

```
this.state.items.filter(e => new Date(e.date) > new Date()).map(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `this.state.items.find`  with `this.state.items.filter` if you need multiple results.

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function

Meaning it only returns first thing it matches with.

(ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

On the other hand

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function

meaning it will return multiple things it matches with

(ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)